# In linear regression, is the $R^2$ value enough to assess whether the relationship between the independent and dependent variable is linear?

Tags: regression, r-squared, diagnostic

In linear regression, is the $R^2$ value enough to assess whether the relationship between the independent and dependent variable is linear? It gives the amount of variability in the dependent variable explained by the independent variable. I know that you can plot residuals versus the x value or residuals versus the y value and see if there is a pattern (if there is a pattern then the relationship is not linear). But doesn't the correlation coefficient give enough information about linearity?

Answer (score 16):

If you look at [Anscombe's quartet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet) you can see examples of linear with noise, linear with outliers and non-linear sets of data with the same $r^2$, means and variances.

This image is from the Wikipedia article
[image]

Comment: +1 To be contrary or irksome, one might argue that in some sense the last three are all "equally" non-linear, but the contrast with the first one (which is a classic linear scatterplot) speaks volumes.

Answer (score 6):

Usually not.  The model

$$y_i = \beta + \varepsilon_i,$$

$\varepsilon \sim \text{iid}$, $\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon]=0$ for the relation between $(y_i)$ and $(x_i)$ is perfectly linear, yet has an $r^2$ of *zero*.

For other examples of what $r^2$ does not say about linearity, see the illustrations in my reply at [Is $R^2$ useful or dangerous?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13314/r-squared-useful-or-dangerous).

Linearity is generally assessed by goodness of fit testing; for instance, by including additional terms in a follow-on regression and testing whether they are both significant and important in the application.  One person's nonlinearity is just another person's randomness, so there's no omnibus method.  Nevertheless, usually $r^2$ is just too crude.

Comment: So is looking at a scatterplot fine (or looking at a residual plot)?

Comment: @question Yes, a plot of residual *vs* fit can tell you a lot.

Comment: If there is a pattern in the residuals vs fit plot.....then there is nonlinearity?

Comment: @question If it (a) is a pattern in which the *mean* residual varies and (b) it would be unacceptable to treat that pattern as random, then--practically by definition--there is nonlinearity.  Some patterns do *not* indicate lack of linearity but suggest other phenomena such as heteroscedasticity, outliers, or high-leverage points, so we shouldn't assume *all* deviations from randomness are evidence of nonlinearity.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the above answers, a commonly used (in econometrics) test for general regression nonlinearity is [Ramsey's RESET test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_RESET_test). Suppose you ran your main regression and obtained residuals $\hat\epsilon_i$ and fitted values $\hat y_i$ in it. Then RESET test is the test of the overall significance in an auxiliary regression of $\hat\epsilon_i$ on powers of $\hat y_i$. From regression geometry, we already know that $\hat\epsilon_i$ are orthogonal to the zeroth and the first power of $\hat y_i$, so it makes sense to run it as $\hat\epsilon_i \sim \hat y_i^2 + \hat y_i^3 + \ldots$, in R-like pseudocode. The test is implemented in R as `resettest` in `lmtest` package, and in Stata, as `estat ovtest` after `regress`.