# How to find out if relationship is linear, without graphing?

Tags: linear

An obvious way to find out whether a relationship between X and Y is linear, is to construct a scatterplot.

But is there any other way, e.g. some statistical test?

My X and Y variables have quite a few data points (e.g. 5K).

Comment: A visual check is often quicker: try [Anscombe's quartet](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16505/2958) to see how fast this can be done.  Quantitative methods, for example on the residuals from a linear fit, will often pick up "statistically significant" deviations from the assumptions, especially when you have a large number of observations,  even when these are small and not worth worrying about.

Comment: 5K datapoints is a very small dataset btw

Comment: You can plot 5k points.

Comment: @Henry is important (check the link), but if you need a direct response to the issue of plot/don't plot, then PLOT THE DATA!

Answer (score 1):

you can test for that by testing if a model that allows for a non-linear effect (e.g., by including polynomial or spline terms) is statistically significantly better than a model that only has a linear effect, for example by using an F-test.